# uibutton text on background image using swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

I am new to IOS swift and i have been trying to solve this problem for the past few days. I am trying to create a UIButton with a background image downloaded from server and add a text on the button itself on top of the background image.

```
for button in data {
            let btn = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 125, 125)
            btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            btn.setTitle(button["button_text"] as NSString, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
            btn.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 15)
            btn.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
            btn.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 5
            btn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
            btn.layer.borderWidth = 1

            var item_image_url:NSString = button["button_image"] as NSString
            var imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: item_image_url)!
            let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
                var image = UIImage(data: data)
                btn.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            })

            self.view.addSubview(btn)
        }
```

Please help! Thanks in advance..

KL

Comment: What have you done so far? Please post your code and specify what went wrong.

Comment: i tried to create the button dynamically, however, only the image is appearing...i have included the code above... thanks..

Answer (score 7):

I had same issue, and found solution.

Use `BackgroundImage` rather than `Image`, and the text will remain visible.

So change:

```
btn.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

into:

```
btn.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Hope this resolves your question as well.

Comment: Hi, If my answer helped you out, can you please click the tick! I need to build up some points....  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
    let imageN = UIImage(named: "imageName.jpg") as UIImage?
    let button = UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 25, 35)
    button .setBackgroundImage(imageN, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.setTitle("Text", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Comment: Ikbal, please add some explanation to your answer.